# CondaValueError during pip install while building Docker image

Tags: python, docker, pip, miniconda

I'm trying to build a Docker image from a Python project that uses an environment built with `conda`. Here's my current Dockerfile:

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda

SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]

ADD . /service

WORKDIR /service

RUN conda env create -n my-env -f=environment.yml

RUN python setup.py develop

RUN source activate my-env

WORKDIR src

CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

The build fails during `conda env create` after trying to download a large dependency from the `pip` section of `environment.yaml`:

```
Collecting mkl==2018.0.3
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/42/65/a761991d954021ce8dbf70fcb7dd52bc8e0c2cd330b6a8c7de5580582483/mkl-2018.0.3-py2.py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (269.2MB)

CondaValueError: pip returned an error.

The command '/bin/bash -c conda env create -n ppm -f=environment.yml' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I've also tried building my image from an Ubuntu image and installing conda manually over it, specifying the version of conda to match what I'm running locally, but it still fails at the same place. The environment build works fine when run locally (on a Mac).

Any idea what the issue is? (or at least if I can see an error message somewhere more detailed than `pip returned an error`)

edit - Here's a more detailed log:

```
Step 5/9 : RUN conda env create -n ppm -f=environment.yml
 ---> Running in 2956e595fa1d
Solving environment: ...working... done
pip-9.0.1            | 1.6 MB    | ########## | 100% 
wheel-0.29.0         | 81 KB     | ########## | 100% 
setuptools-36.4.0    | 557 KB    | ########## | 100% 
python-2.7.13        | 11.5 MB   | ########## | 100% 
zlib-1.2.11          | 109 KB    | ########## | 100% 
readline-6.2         | 606 KB    | ########## | 100% 
libpq-9.5.4          | 93 KB     | ########## | 100% 
openssl-1.0.2l       | 3.2 MB    | ########## | 100% 
tk-8.5.18            | 1.9 MB    | ########## | 100% 
certifi-2016.2.28    | 211 KB    | ########## | 100% 
sqlite-3.13.0        | 4.0 MB    | ########## | 100% 
psycopg2-2.7.1       | 435 KB    | ########## | 100% 

Downloading and Extracting Packages
Preparing transaction: ...working... done
Verifying transaction: ...working... done
Executing transaction: ...working... done
Collecting chardet==3.0.4 (from -r /service/condaenv.FWKDwj.requirements.txt (line 1))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bc/a9/01ffebfb562e4274b6487b4bb1ddec7ca55ec7510b22e4c51f14098443b8/chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133kB)
Collecting click==6.7 (from -r /service/condaenv.FWKDwj.requirements.txt (line 2))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/34/c1/8806f99713ddb993c5366c362b2f908f18269f8d792aff1abfd700775a77/click-6.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (71kB)
Collecting dill==0.2.8.2 (from -r /service/condaenv.FWKDwj.requirements.txt (line 3))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6f/78/8b96476f4ae426db71c6e86a8e6a81407f015b34547e442291cd397b18f3/dill-0.2.8.2.tar.gz (150kB)
Collecting flask==1.0.2 (from -r /service/condaenv.FWKDwj.requirements.txt (line 4))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7f/e7/08578774ed4536d3242b14dacb4696386634607af824ea997202cd0edb4b/Flask-1.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (91kB)
Collecting icc-rt==2018.0.3 (from -r /service/condaenv.FWKDwj.requirements.txt (line 5))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/84/32/15087ef76af6bb54d008e10bf7a425ce84140bc20b06f491faf212c08b47/icc_rt-2018.0.3-py2.py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (12.0MB)
Collecting idna==2.6 (from -r /service/condaenv.FWKDwj.requirements.txt (line 6))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/27/cc/6dd9a3869f15c2edfab863b992838277279ce92663d334df9ecf5106f5c6/idna-2.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (56kB)
Collecting intel-numpy==1.14.3 (from -r /service/condaenv.FWKDwj.requirements.txt (line 7))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b4/12/c058933174b68a293be75adc38eb25ca812161b060e251569ccb0a4b1d87/intel_numpy-1.14.3-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (6.0MB)
Collecting intel-openmp==2018.0.3 (from -r /service/condaenv.FWKDwj.requirements.txt (line 8))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8d/1f/9080b1e64054de729bd93953a65029f3cf1b2606125f8b63da21f0583797/intel_openmp-2018.0.3-py2.py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (714kB)
Collecting itsdangerous==0.24 (from -r /service/condaenv.FWKDwj.requirements.txt (line 9))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/dc/b4/a60bcdba945c00f6d608d8975131ab3f25b22f2bcfe1dab221165194b2d4/itsdangerous-0.24.tar.gz (46kB)
Collecting jinja2==2.10 (from -r /service/condaenv.FWKDwj.requirements.txt (line 10))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7f/ff/ae64bacdfc95f27a016a7bed8e8686763ba4d277a78ca76f32659220a731/Jinja2-2.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl (126kB)
Collecting markupsafe==1.0 (from -r /service/condaenv.FWKDwj.requirements.txt (line 11))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4d/de/32d741db316d8fdb7680822dd37001ef7a448255de9699ab4bfcbdf4172b/MarkupSafe-1.0.tar.gz
Collecting mkl==2018.0.3 (from -r /service/condaenv.FWKDwj.requirements.txt (line 12))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/42/65/a761991d954021ce8dbf70fcb7dd52bc8e0c2cd330b6a8c7de5580582483/mkl-2018.0.3-py2.py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (269.2MB)

CondaValueError: pip returned an error

The command '/bin/bash -c conda env create -n ppm -f=environment.yml' returned a non-zero code: 1
```